# Unexpected result in R for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I don't know why this isn't giving me the desired results.

Here is my vector:

```
flowers = c("Flower", "Flower", "Vegatative", "Vegatative", "Dead")
```

Here is my for loop:

```
   Na = 0
for (i in 1:length(flowers)){
  if (i != "Dead"){
    Na = Na + 1
  }
}
Na
```

Obviously Na should equal 4, but it gives me a result of 5. When I print the flower's status it prints all 5. I don't want it to read the last one. What's my problem?

Thank you.

Comment: `i` is a number between 1 and 5. It will never be `"Dead"`.

Comment: `if (flowers[i] != "Dead")`

Comment: or `for (i in flowers)` would work

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be trying to count the number of values in `flowers` that are not equal to "Dead". In R, the way to do this would be:

```
sum(flowers != "Dead")
# [1] 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug in your code is this line:

```
if (i != "Dead"){
```

To understand why, it would be best to print out the values of `i` in the loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(flowers)){
  print(i)
}
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
```

That is, you are iterating over numbers (indices of a vector), but not actually selecting the value from the vector when you do the test.  To access the values, use `flowers[i]`:

```
for (i in 1:length(flowers)){
  print(flowers[i])
}
[1] "Flower"
[1] "Flower"
[1] "Vegatative"
[1] "Vegatative"
[1] "Dead"
```

And so, the answer to your original question is this:

```
Na = 0
for (i in 1:length(flowers)){
  if (flowers[i] != "Dead"){
    Na = Na + 1
  }
}
Na
[4]
```

R offers a lot of facilities for doing computations like this without a loop - it's called vectorization.  A good article on it is John Cook's [5 Kinds of Subscripts in R](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/10/23/five-kinds-of-r-language-subscripts/).  For example, you could get the same result like this:

```
length(flowers[flowers != "Dead"])
[1] 4
```